# How to align objects to different sides in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx

I have a `StackPane` inside of which I have `Region` and `Button`. Why `StackPane`? I need my button to be going on top of `Region`. I want my region to be algned to left side of `StackPane` and my button to right one. Can it be done via CSS?

[image]

Comment: I don't think it can be done with CSS, but you can certainly do this using the `StackPane` layout constraints: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javafx/scene/layout/StackPane.html#setAlignment-javafx.scene.Node-javafx.geometry.Pos-

Comment: If this is just a visual effect, you could use 2 backgrounds for the button: one for the purple part and one for the blue part and use `-fx-padding` to make sure the label does not overlap the purple part...